# Image binding in listbox and free resources

Tags: windows-phone, out-of-memory

I'm developing a Windows Phone application in which i'm loading many images in a listbox among with some other properties.

Due to the images i'm getting Oout of memory exception and I've read that one solution is to set the image source to null so it will free the resources used.

I was wondering, do I have to gather all images from the listbox and set the Image property to null or doing Posters.Source = null applies to all items in the listbox.

below I post the code from my data template

```
<Image  Height="213" Width="130"  Source="/Assets/Images/transparent.png"/>
<Image Name="Posters" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Poster}" Height="205" Width="130"  Margin="0,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
```